# Filter ArrayList based on Object Parameters and input from user

Tags: java, arraylist, input, filtering, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Kommandozeilenmenue {
Scanner scan;
Medienbibliothek mb = new Medienbibliothek();


public Kommandozeilenmenue() {
    this.scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    bisherigeMedien();
}

public void bisherigeMedien() {
    Medien m1 = new Filme("Java Wars", "Claudio Landerer", "25.10.2018", 150, true, false);
    Medien m2 = new EBooks("Cloverfield Paradox", "Julius Onah", "25.10.2018", 12345678, 120, 100000);
    Medien m3 = new Filme("Haus des Geldes", "Alex Pina", "01.11.2018", 200, false, true);
    Medien m4 = new EBooks("Poltergeist", "Tobe Hooper", "01.11.2018", 87654321, 175, 100);

    mb.medienHinzufuegen(m1);
    mb.medienHinzufuegen(m2);
    mb.medienHinzufuegen(m3);
    mb.medienHinzufuegen(m4);
}


public void MenueAnzeigen() {
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("HAUPTMENÜ");
    System.out.println("1) HINZUFÜGEN");
    System.out.println("2) FILTERN");
    System.out.println("3) LISTE-AUSGEBEN");
    System.out.println("4) exit");
}

public void unterMenueHinzufügen() {
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("HINZUFÜGENMENÜ");
    System.out.println("1) FILM-HINZUFÜGEN");
    System.out.println("2) EBOOK-HINZUFÜGEN");
    System.out.println("3) Zurück");
}

public void unterMenueFiltern() {
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("FILTERMENÜ");
    System.out.println("1) FILTERN");
    System.out.println("2) Zurück");
}

public void unterMenueListe() {
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("LISTENMENÜ");
    System.out.println("1) FILME");
    System.out.println("2) EBOOKS");
    System.out.println("3) DETAILS");
    System.out.println("4) KURZ");
    System.out.println("5) Zurück");
}


public void start() {
    MenueAnzeigen();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scan.nextLine();

    //Möglichkeit 1 wurde gewählt
    if(s.equals("1")) {
        unterMenueHinzufügen();
        s = scan.nextLine();
        if(s.equals("1")) {
            filmHinzufügen();
        }else if(s.equals("2")) {
            bookHinzufügen();
        }else if(s.equals("3")) {
            start();
        }else {
            fehler();
        }
    }
    //Möglichkeit 2 wurde gewählt
    else if(s.equals("2")) {
        unterMenueFiltern();
        s = scan.nextLine();
        if(s.equals("1")) {
            mediumFiltern();
        }else if(s.equals("2")) {
            start();
        }else {
            fehler();
        }
    }
        //Möglichkeit 3 wurde gewählt
    else if(s.equals("3")) {
        unterMenueListe();
        s = scan.nextLine();
        if(s.equals("1")) {
            filmListeAusgeben();
            start();
        }else if(s.equals("2")) {
            bookListeAusgeben();
            start();
        }else if(s.equals("3")) {
            listeAusgeben();
            start();
        }else if(s.equals("4")) {
            mb.kurzBeschreibung();
            start();
        }else if(s.equals("5")) {
            start();
        }else {
            fehler();
        }
    }
        //Möglichkeit 4 wurde gewählt
    else if(s.equals("4")) {
        System.out.println("Auf Wiedersehen!");
    }
    //Fehlermeldung bei ungültiger Eingabe
    else {
        fehler();
    }
    scan.close();
}


public void listeAusgeben() {
    mb.anzeigen();
}

public void fehler()
{
    System.out.println("Sie können nur 1, 2, 3 oder 4 eingeben!");
}

//Wenn Fall 1 eintritt --> weitere Entscheidungsmöglichkeiten
public void filmHinzufügen() {
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie den Namen des neuen Films ein:");
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie einen Kommentar zu dem neuen Film ein:");
    String kommentar = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie das Erscheinungsdatum des neuen Films ein:");
    String datum = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie die Spielzeit des neuen Films ein:");
    int spielzeit = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ist der Film UHD?");
    boolean uhd = scan.nextBoolean();
    System.out.println("Ist der Film HD?");
    boolean hd = scan.nextBoolean();

    Medien m5 = new Filme(name, kommentar, datum, spielzeit, uhd, hd);
    mb.medienHinzufuegen(m5);
    start();
}

public void filmListeAusgeben() {
    for(Filme filme : mb.alleFilmeAlsListe())
    {
        filme.anzeigen();
    }
    start();
}

//Wenn Fall 2 eintritt --> weitere Entscheidungsmöglichkeiten
public void bookHinzufügen() {
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie den Namen des neuen eBooks ein:");
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie einen Kommentar zu dem neuen eBook ein:");
    String kommentar = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie das Erscheinungsdatum des neuen eBooks ein:");
    String datum = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie die ISBN-Nummer des neuen eBooks ein:");
    int isbn = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie die Seitenanzahl des neuen eBooks ein:");
    int seiten = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie die Auflagszahl des neuen eBooks ein:");
    int auflage = scan.nextInt();

    Medien m6 = new EBooks(name, kommentar, datum, isbn, seiten, auflage);
    mb.medienHinzufuegen(m6);
    start();
}

public void mediumFiltern() {
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie den Namen des gesuchten Films ein:");
    String s = scan.nextLine();

    for(Medien m : mb) {
        if(m.contains(s)) {
            System.out.println(m);
        }

    }

}

public void bookListeAusgeben() {
    for(EBooks ebooks : mb.alleEBooksAlsListe())
    {
        ebooks.anzeigen();
    }
    start();
}
```

}

This is my class Kommandozeilenmenü. In it I create an ArrayList from the type Medien. Also i create a scanner to track the users input. Medien is superclass of EBooks and Filme because they are very similar. My task is to filter the ArrayList based on the users input. The users input could be any field from the Object Medien. Here is the Medien class.

```
    public class Medien{

    private int id;
    protected String name;
    private String kommentar;
    private String erscheinungsdatum;
    private static int counter;

    public Medien(String name, String kommentar, String erscheinungsdatum) {
        super();
        counter++;
        this.id = counter;
        this.name = name;
        this.kommentar = kommentar;
        this.erscheinungsdatum = erscheinungsdatum;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getKommentar() {
        return kommentar;
    }

    public void setKommentar(String kommentar) {
        this.kommentar = kommentar;
    }

    public String getErscheinungsdatum() {
        return erscheinungsdatum;
    }

    public void setErscheinungsdatum(String erscheinungsdatum) {
        this.erscheinungsdatum = erscheinungsdatum;
    }

    public boolean equals(Medien other) {
        if(this.id == other.id) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
            }
        }

    public  void anzeigen()
    {
        System.out.println("\n"+"-----------------------------------------"+"\n"+"\n"+"[Medium]:"+"\n"+ "ID -->                " + this.getId() + "\n"+ "Name -->              " + this.getName() + "\n"  + "Kommentar -->         " + this.getKommentar()+ "\n"  + "Erscheinungsdatum --> " + this.getErscheinungsdatum());
    }

    public void entfernungsBeschreibung() {
        System.out.println("ID, Name, Typ -->     " + this.getId()+ ", " + this.getClass() + ", "+ this.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have different predicates for your members in static methods and use them when filtering. Note that for the two first I included both equals and contains depending on how you want tot search, you could of course implement both versions.

In the Medien class:

```
public static Predicate<Medien> nameFilter(String name) {
    //return m -> m.getName().equals(name);
    return m -> m.getName().contains(name);
}

public static Predicate<Medien> kommentar Filter(String kommentar) {
    //return m -> m.getKommentar().equals(kommentar);
    return m -> m.getKommentar().contains(kommentar);
}

public static Predicate<Medien> erscheinungsdatum Filter(String name) {
    return m -> m.getErscheinungsdatum().equals(erscheinungsdatum);
}
```

And then use them like so

```
mb.stream().filter(Medien.nameFilter("Java"));
mb.stream().filter(Medien.kommentarFilter("Alex Pina");
```

Note that in your code `mb` is a `Medienbibliothek` object which I don't know what it is so in my examples `mb` is an `ArrayList` object.

Answer (score 0):

Use java streams for filtering.

Store all the Medien objects in an originalList.

```
List<Medien> originalList = new ArrayList<>();

    Medien m1 = new Filme("Java Wars", "Claudio Landerer", "25.10.2018", 150, true, false);
    Medien m2 = new EBooks("Cloverfield Paradox", "Julius Onah", "25.10.2018", 12345678, 120, 100000);
    Medien m3 = new Filme("Haus des Geldes", "Alex Pina", "01.11.2018", 200, false, true);
    Medien m4 = new EBooks("Poltergeist", "Tobe Hooper", "01.11.2018", 87654321, 175, 100);

   originalList.add(m1);
   originalList.add(m2);
   originalList.add(m3);
   originalList.add(m4);
```

Now create a method for each type of filtered data. 
For example:
For filtering based on name have a method like below.

```
List<Medien> getListBasedOnName(String name){
  return originalList.stream.filter(value -> 
  value.getName().equals(name)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Similar methods needs to be created for each attribute on which filtering is required.